# How to compile gather?

Tags: compile

First question，How to Compile this？

```
gather[data_]:=Gather[data, Mod[#1, 3] == Mod[#2, 3] &]
```

I dont know why this is wrong.

```
cf = Compile[{{data, _Integer, 1}}, Gather[data, Mod[#1, 3] == Mod[#2, 3] &]]
cf[Range[9]]
cf[Range[10]]
```

Second question，How to Compile this？

```
gather[data_] := Gather[data, Count[#1, 0] == Count[#2, 0] &]
gather[RandomInteger[{0, 5}, {10, 5}]]
```

Comment: I don't believe that `Gather` is compilable. You can see a list of compilable functions in the answers to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions).

Comment: Not every function can be compiled.  `Gather` cannot be compiled.  The reason why `Gather` is not compilable is that it returns a ragged array and compiled code doesn't support ragged arrays.

Comment: sorry...My memory is wrong...but if i change gather to tally ,how to compile second situation？

Comment: @Chenminqi In the second situation is every sublist of `data` of the same length?  This is necessary to make it compilable.  Vectorization may be better though.  `Tally@Total[1-Unitize[data],{2}]` should do it if I didn't make a mistake (untested).

Answer (score 4):

Not every function can be compiled by `Compile`, and those functions which are supported are often supported only partially, for numerical arguments only.

`Gather` cannot be compiled.  The reason for this is that `Gather` will usually return a ragged array and compiled functions can only work with full (i.e. rectangular), homogeneous  numerical arrays.